# Angular 2 manipulate DOM - move component from one place to another while preserving functions

Tags: javascript, angular

Ok so I have:

```
<div class="full"></div>
<div class="grid>
    <div class="widget"><widget1></widget1></div>
    <div class="widget"><widget2></widget2></div>
    <div class="widget"><widget3></widget2></div>
    <div class="widget"><widget4></widget2></div>
</div>
```

Each widget is a component, that has a button with:

```
<div class="resize" (click)="resize($elem)"></div>
```

Now, when the user clicks on the resize button on each of the components, I want that component to be moved on the div with the class full, and removed from the grid, and when clicked on the maximized one, but back in it's place and removed from the full div.

I need this with pure javascript.

Comment: Not sure whats the catch. Isn't it enough to select element, append it to the div.full and then remove it from its original position? Or the opposite order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Michal, if there's no catch, it could be just something like this:

```
function resize(element) {
   var where = element.parentNode.className;
    if(where=="full"){
        document.querySelector(".grid").appendChild(element);
    } else {
        document.querySelector(".full").appendChild(element);
    }
}
```